# SQL Delete All Column Values Older Than 20min

Tags: php, sql, cron, sql-delete

Tonight I'm going to start working on a php script to set as a cron. The script is going to delete all the values of a particular column that are older than 20min. It's going to do this by checking the timestamp of when the value that will be deleted was entered. The timestamp will be stored as another column value on the table.

It seems like a pretty simple script to write, but my knowledge of SQL is lacking. I know I can compare the times in PHP, but I was just reading that it's possible to do it all in a SQL statement as well. If someone can please correct my delete statement it would be appreciated.

```
$query ="DELETE `key` FROM $table WHERE `time`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE);"
```

I need this statement to check the key value for the whole table, and I'm not exactly sure which PHP time function corresponds with the SQL comparison. Would I just use `DateTime();` to set the timestamp?

Comment: In SQL, `delete` removes rows not columns.  What you are asking for is unclear.

Comment: Post some sample data, and what you want the result to be.

Comment: Maybe you actually want to do something like `UPDATE $table SET key = NULL WHERE ...` instead of `DELETE` ?  I'm guessing

Comment: @Kevin Good call I'll update the value instead of delete. But I'm still unclear about the proper SQL statement and the PHP function I should use to set the time that will be in the correct format for the SQL time check.  And I need it to check and update the whole table. `UPDATE $table SET key = NULL WHERE time <DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE);"`

Comment: Do I need to set and compare a time or does SQL know when a value was set for this `<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE);` to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE `key` FROM $table WHERE `time` < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 MINUTE)";
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I get this far w/ the function. Which php function should I use to set "time" and does it need to be formatted? I don't want to delete the entire row so I'll be trying this with UPDATE.

Comment: For setting time: `$time_zone = date_default_timezone_get();` For setting a default time zone: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` List of Supported Timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```
$query = "DELETE `key` FROM $table WHERE `time` < CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE -20";
```